# Finding Spatial Data for US Metropolitan Statistical Areas

Tags: usa

I am looking to map (US) Metropolitan Statistical Areas, but do not have a source for the Spatial Data needed to do this.   Can somebody point me to a public data source?

Comment: openstreetmap.org and census.gov may be helpful.

Comment: Apologies, maybe the request was unclear - I am looking for geographical information for each defined MSA to allow me to create a graphic.  Eg, for a given MSA, instructions to draw the (approximate) shape on the map.

Comment: I think both my references provide polygonal data -- census.gov should provide polygonal data that comprises a given MSA, since I think they're the ones who define MSAs. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Indeed, it is on census.gov.    My bad.  Apologies, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Response from @Barry Carter solved my question:

census.gov should provide polygonal data that comprises a given MSA, since I think they're the ones who define MSAs.

Tnx, Barry!